# How to ask for password for emptying the trash?

Tags: permissions, password, trash

Is there any way I can enforce the system to ask for the password (or elevated privileges) in order to definitively clean the bin? 
(It's just kinda "dude are you really sure you want to permanently delete everything" - serious thought, not just hitting "sure")